# ViewPager binding issues with ViewModel

Tags: android, binding, android-viewpager, mvvmcross

I am using a ViewPager to implement tabs in MvvmCross 4.0.0-beta5. However, EditText binding property of ViewModel is always null. I also tried updating to MvvmCross 4.0.0-beta7, but no luck.

Here is my ViewPager

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/mspManagerToolbar"
        layout="@layout/mspmanagertoolbar" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        local:tabGravity="fill"
        local:tabMode="scrollable" />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        local:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Here is my tab view

```
<EditText
    ...
    local:MvxBind="Text Title" />
```

The above EditText binding not working. Title always getting null.

```
<EditText
    ...
    local:MvxBind="Text User.Title" />
```

Above EditText binding working perfect. User.Title getting correct value.

Here ViewPagerView.cs code

```
public class CustomerDetailView : MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity<CustomerDetailViewModel>
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.CustomerDetailView);

        // Use toolbar as action bar
        var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.mspManagerToolbar);

        if (toolbar != null)
        {
            // Toolbar will now take on default actionbar characteristics
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        }

        // View Pager
        var viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
        if (viewPager != null)
        {
            // Add tabs in view pager
            var fragments = new List<MvxFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo>
            {
                new MvxFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo(TAB_DETAIL, typeof(Tab_CustomerDetail), typeof(CustomerDetailViewModel)),
                new MvxFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo(TAB_CONTACT, typeof(Tab_CustomerContact), typeof(CustomerDetailViewModel)),
                new MvxFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo(TAB_LOCATION, typeof(Tab_CustomerLocation), typeof(CustomerDetailViewModel)),
                new MvxFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo(TAB_CONTRACT, typeof(Tab_CustomerContract), typeof(CustomerDetailViewModel))                   
            };
            viewPager.Adapter = new MvxFragmentStatePagerAdapter(this, SupportFragmentManager, fragments);
        }

        var tabLayout = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);
        tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

Here is my Fragment Code

```
[Register("app.droid.views.fragments.Tab_CustomerDetail")]
public class Tab_CustomerDetail : MvxFragment
{        

    #region Public Method

    /// <summary>
    /// tab customer detail view
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inflater"></param>
    /// <param name="container"></param>
    /// <param name="savedInstanceState"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override View OnCreateView(Android.Views.LayoutInflater inflater, Android.Views.ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.frg_tab_CustomerDetail, null);


        return view;
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Here is ViewModel Properties

```
public string Title
{
    get
    {
        return (title);
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != title)
        {
            title = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Title);
        }
    }
}

public User User
{
    get
    {
        return (repositoryService.User);
    }
    set
    {
        repositoryService.User = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => User);
    }
}
```

Title property getting null and User.Title is working perfect. So please let me know where I going wrong ?

Comment: What does your adapter setup look like?

Comment: @DerekBeattie : I updated my post, now added view pager layout and MvxFragmentStatePagerAdapter. Please look once and help to resolve.

Comment: What does fragment code look like?

Comment: @DerekBeattie : Updated code with fragment code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i save my data from activity, so i did not getting value of view. Because for every fragment it create new instance of view model, since not getting updated value of view. Now I save my data from fragment and now i getting all values of view in view model.

Comment: view pager binding object becomes null after alert dialog appears and dismiss.  do you have any idea about it how can I fix it. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Does changing property fix it?

```
public string Title
{
    get
    {
        return title;
    }
    set
    {
        title = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry @Derek, actually it is not binding issue. The issue is view call init() of view model 3 times. In first call all property set correctly but android view call again 2 times init() and set all property null. Now looking for it. Do you have any idea why view call view model constructor and init() more than one time ??

Comment: Virwpager will load at least one page before and after the current page.  That might explain Init being called 3 times since there is one viewmodel type.

Comment: yes, you are correct @Derek, if I comment viewpager code then it call only one time init(). So now how to resolve it ? I have only one view model type and like this in my app various places same situation occurred.

Comment: If I add only one fragment then also it called init() 2 times.

Comment: Its ok that it does that.  `MvxFragmentStatePagerAdapter` creates a new instance of `CustomerDetailViewModel` for each view.  Do you have code somewhere I could look at or a sample?

Comment: I using this link [https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples/Example.Droid/Fragments](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples/Example.Droid/Fragments). In this project Martinj added main activity to host fragment but I just implement simple tabs, so I using viewpager as shown above.

Comment: I can't see any problems, did you try removing `if (value != title)`

Comment: @UddhaoPachrne ping me in the #mvvmcross room and I'll try and help.

Comment: I have added demo project here : [https://github.com/Uddhao/MvvmCross-Droid](https://github.com/Uddhao/MvvmCross-Droid)

Comment: @UddhaoPachrne did you find a solution for this? I'm also looking for using tabs with the same viewmodel but it's creating a new instance of the the viewmodel per fragment